# Using a ternary operator to set a variable

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to use a ternary operator to check if the value of an XML element is null. If it is then I want the variable to be one thing. If not then I would like it to return the value of element. This is what I have so far.

```
var rating = data.getElementsByTagName("overall_average")[0].childeNodes[0].length > 0 ? data.getElementsByTagName("overall_average")[0].childeNodes[0].nodeValue : "It is empty";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortest way:

```
var rating = (data.getElementsByTagName('overall_average')[0].childNodes[0] || {}).nodeValue || 'It is empty';
```

Comment: @mplungjan, I used `||` operator to check for null in my example. So, if you have something like this: `var x = null || {};` then x will be an empty `object` instead of `null`. You can use `||` for properties as well: `var x = {}.someProp || 'hello';`, x will be `'hello'`.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to explain how I would then check if this same variable is a number in a ternary operator?

Comment: @Greg Wiley, unfortunately `||` helps you detect only `null/undefined` objects. In case of number detection you need to use usual ternary operator: `isNaN('bla-bla') ? 'not a number' : 'a valid number'`.

Answer (score 20):

Here:

```
var node = data.getElementsByTagName( 'overall_average' )[0].childNodes[0];
var rating = node ? node.nodeValue : 'It is empty';
```

Note that this code throws (an error) in case there is not a single "overall_average" element in `data`, so you might want to guard against that case if necessary...

Comment: It continues to throw NaN as the value of rating.

Comment: I don't see why it would do that. We are merely referencing a node and accessing its `nodeValue`. I recommend setting a break-point and checking if `node` is indeed a Node reference...

Comment: Thanks. I did just that. There was a plugin that was trying to round the rating variable. Moved my coded into an anonymous function and that did the trick. For future reference, though, do you know how to check if a variable is a number and spit out something based on the result? I would again prefer it to be in a ternary operator.

Comment: @GregWiley You could use the prefix `+` operator to coerce the value to a Number value and then check if the result is a number other than `NaN`: `var result = !isNaN( +value ) ? +value : 0;` (here `0` is the fallback value).

Answer (score 2):

Your ternary operation look fine to me. One thing I would suggest (for readability and brevity) is to define your `overall_average` object as a variable and reference it after.

```
var overall_average = data.getElementsByTagName("overall_average")[0].childeNodes[0];
var rating = overall_average.length > 0 ? overall_average.nodeValue : "It is empty";
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense, but sense I am running through a list of element this would be two lines per variable I'm trying to set.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered sufficiently but just for fun I thought I'd simplify it for anyone else who might stumble upon it and show a slightly alternative use case for ternary assignment.

```
var thingToCheck = '';

// check if the variable is set or is "truthy", then either assign it
// to itself or set a new value

thingToCheck = thingToCheck || 'Hello World!';

// `thingToCheck` is already set or is "truthy" so this line will do nothing
thingToCheck = thingToCheck || 'Nothing to see here';

console.log(thingToCheck) // Output = 'Hello World!'
```